# What are the 'Data' and 'value' keywords in SQL Server 2019, and how do they work?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am working with SQL Server 2019 (standalone server, non-Azure), and I am executing a bath. Following is the batch:

```
WITH Data (value) AS
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION  ALL
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0   
      WHEN MAX(1/value) >= 100 THEN 1   
   END   
FROM Data ;
```

I did a lot of research but could not understand what are the `Data` and `value` keywords in SQL Server, and how exactly this batch is working.
Can someone please help me out?

When I run the batch, I get the following expected error:

```
Divide by zero error encountered
```

Comment: do u overcome this error?

Comment: @RahulBiswas I copied the code from a website, and they say that I should be getting the error, when I run this query. Following is the website from where I copied the code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Read the Remarks in the link you site: Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE expression are evaluated first, then provided to the CASE expression. For example, the following query produces a divide by zero error when producing the value of the MAX aggregate. This occurs prior to evaluating the CASE expression. So a value of zero will case the above script to fail independently of the `SELECT` clauses.

Comment: @PeterSmith But what do the `Data` and the `value` keywords stand for? this is the first time I am encountering them...

Comment: See the answer below as to what `Data` and `value` are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data` and `value` are are not "magic" keywords. if you try:

```
WITH Data (value) AS
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION  ALL
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT       
   value
FROM Data ;
```

This returns the two rows with values `0` and `1`. 'Data' here is a `CTE` (common table expressions) and `value` is the output parameter. The link you mention is merely using the CTE to illustrate that the aggregate `MAX(1/value)` will be evaluated before the `CASE` and so will always fail.

This fails in the same way:

```
WITH MyCTE (param) AS
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION  ALL
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN MIN(param) <= 0 THEN 0   
      WHEN MAX(1/param) >= 100 THEN 1   
   END   
   
FROM MyCTE ;
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid Divide by zero error use non zero value as divisor. If divisor is zero then convert it to non zero by adding any number as per business.

```
MAX(1/ CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE value END)
```

Also the full code

```
WITH Data (value) AS
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION  ALL
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0   
      WHEN MAX(1/CASE WHEN value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE value END) >= 100 THEN 1   
   END   
FROM Data ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your division by zero, a handy terse way of preventing such an error is to use `nullif`

```
WITH Data (value) AS
(   
SELECT 0   
UNION  ALL
SELECT 1   
)   
SELECT   
   CASE   
      WHEN MIN(value) <= 0 THEN 0   
      WHEN MAX(1/NullIf(value,0)) >= 100 THEN 1   
   END   
FROM Data;
```